# Align text below rotated div

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

i need some help with centering a text below a rotated div.

I can place the text on the div, but not below and in center.

HTML:

```
<div id="contact_main2">

<div id="marker_align"

<div class="marker">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="marker">
</div>
<div class="marker">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

The whole code:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVsxF/

Hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating out the `<p>` tag from inside the marker `<div>`:

HTML:

```
<div id="marker_align">

<!-- changed in EDIT -->
<div class="marker-group">
  <div class="marker"></div>
  <div class="marker"></div>
  <div class="marker"></div>
</div>

  <div class="marker-label">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="marker-label">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="marker-label">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

In your CSS, delete the `.marker p` rule and add this:

```
.marker-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 20px;
}

.marker-label p {
    text-align: center;
}

/* added in EDIT */
.marker-group {
    clear: right;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GVsxF/3/)

**EDIT**

Added `.marker-group` and `clear:right` to prevent text from moving on browser re sizing. This will need additional improvements if browser is re sized to smaller width. JSFiddle has been updated to reflect changes

Comment: thank you, but...
now the "text-row" are just below the div on resizing the window.
But the text should be always "fixed" it.

Comment: @Dennis made a few changes that should fix that issue

Comment: ah, i just find another issue...a longer text wont be in center.
Is there any solution?

Comment: @Dennis can you show an example? Do you want it on one line? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVsxF/7/)

Comment: @peter like in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVsxF/8/

how can i get it in center?

Comment: in this case, the text is extending beyond the set `45px` width of the `.marker-label` div, so it won't be able to center. You'll need to increase the width for this and the `.marker-group` div to display properly with longer text